# SQLAlchemy - Making a hybrid_property which utilizes multiple relationships queryable

Tags: python, properties, sqlalchemy, comparator

I have a Flask-SQLAlchemy model that contains several relationships to tables for holding quantities in decimal, fraction, and integer:

```
class Packet(db.Model):
    # ...
    qty_decimal_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('qty_decimals.id'))
    _qty_decimal = db.relationship('QtyDecimal', backref='_packets')
    qty_fraction_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('qty_fractions.id'))
    _qty_fraction = db.relationship('QtyFraction', backref='_packets')
    qty_integer_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('qty_integers.id'))
    _qty_integer = db.relationship('QtyInteger', backref='_packets')
    # ...
```

The tables each contain a column named 'value' that contains the actual value, such that if I want to store an integer quantity of '100', I would store it in ._qty_integer.value. I have created a hybrid_property that currently gets whichever of these relationships is not null, and sets to a relevant relationship depending on what kind of data is detected by the setter:

```
@hybrid_property
def quantity(self):
    retqty = None
    for qty in [self._qty_decimal, self._qty_fraction, self._qty_integer]:
        if qty is not None:
            if retqty is None:
                retqty = qty
            else:
                raise RuntimeError('More than one type of quantity'
                                   ' was detected for this packet. Only'
                                   ' one type of quantity may be set!')
    return retqty.value

@quantity.setter
def quantity(self, value):
    if is_decimal(value):
        self.clear_quantity()
        self._qty_decimal = QtyDecimal.query.filter_by(value=value).\
            first() or QtyDecimal(value)
    elif is_fraction(value):
        if is_480th(value):
            self.clear_quantity()
            self._qty_fraction = QtyFraction.query.filter_by(value=value).\
                first() or QtyFraction(value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Fractions must have denominators'
                             ' 480 is divisible by!')
    elif is_int(value):
        self.clear_quantity()
        self._qty_integer = QtyInteger.query.filter_by(value=value).\
            first() or QtyInteger(value)
    else:
        raise ValueError('Could not determine appropriate type for '
                         'quantity! Please make sure it is a integer, '
                         'decimal number, or fraction.')
```

The getter and setter for .quantity work perfectly as far as I can tell (it's always possible I missed some edge cases in my test suite) but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to implement a comparator or expression such that one could, for example, get all packets that have a quantity of 100, or all packets with a quantity of 1/4. (Units are implemented too, but irrelevant to this question.) As far as I can tell it's not doable as an expression, but it should be doable as a comparator. I can't figure out how to pull it off, though. So far this is my best attempt at a comparator:

```
class QuantityComparator(Comparator):
    def __init__(self, qty_decimal, qty_fraction, qty_integer):
        self.qty_decimal = qty_decimal
        self.qty_fraction = qty_fraction
        self.qty_integer = qty_integer

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if is_decimal(other):
            return self.qty_decimal.value == other
        elif is_fraction(other):
            if is_480th(other):
                return self.qty_fraction.value == other
            else:
                raise ValueError('Cannot query using a fraction with a '
                                 'denominator 480 is not divisible by!')
        elif is_int(other):
            return self.qty_fraction.value == other
        else:
            raise ValueError('Could not parse query value'
                             ' as a valid quantity!')

@quantity.comparator
def quantity(self):
    return self.QuantityComparator(self._qty_decimal,
                                    self._qty_fraction,
                                    self._qty_integer)
```

Unsurprisingly, this does not work, when I try to run Packet.query.filter_by(quantity=) it raises an exception:

```
 AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Packet._qty_fraction has an attribute 'value'
```

If the solution to getting this use case to work is in the SQLAlchemy docs, I've either missed it or (more likely) haven't wrapped my head around enough of SQLAlchemy yet to figure it out.

I have come up with a stopgap solution that at least lets users get Packets based on quantity:

```
@staticmethod
def quantity_equals(value):
    if is_decimal(value):
        return Packet.query.join(Packet._qty_decimal).\
                filter(QtyDecimal.value == value)
    elif is_fraction(value):
        if is_480th(value):
            return Packet.query.join(Packet._qty_fraction).\
                filter(QtyFraction.value == value)
        else:
            raise ValueError('Fraction could not be converted to 480ths!')
    elif is_int(value):
        return Packet.query.join(Packet._qty_integer).\
            filter(QtyInteger.value == value)
```

This works and gets me what looks to be the correct Query object, as shown by this test:

```
def test_quantity_equals(self):
    pkt1 = Packet()
    pkt2 = Packet()
    pkt3 = Packet()
    db.session.add_all([pkt1, pkt2, pkt3])
    pkt1.quantity = Decimal('3.14')
    pkt2.quantity = Fraction(1, 4)
    pkt3.quantity = 100
    db.session.commit()
    qty_dec_query = Packet.quantity_equals(Decimal('3.14'))
    self.assertIs(pkt1, qty_dec_query.first())
    self.assertEqual(qty_dec_query.count(), 1)
    qty_frac_query = Packet.quantity_equals(Fraction(1, 4))
    self.assertIs(pkt2, qty_frac_query.first())
    self.assertEqual(qty_frac_query.count(), 1)
    qty_int_query = Packet.quantity_equals(100)
    self.assertIs(pkt3, qty_int_query.first())
    self.assertEqual(qty_int_query.count(), 1)
```

I can easily make similar dirty methods to substitute for other comparison operators, but I would think it's possible to do it in a custom comparator such as the aforementioned QuantityComparator, or to otherwise achieve the desired ability to use the .quantity property in query filters.

Can anybody help me get the QuantityComparator working, or point me in the right direction for figuring it out myself?

**Edit: Solution**

While I haven't actually solved the explicit question of making a hybrid_property with multiple relationships queryable, I have solved the core issue of representing a quantity that could either be `int`, `float` (I use `float` instead of `Decimal` here because no arithmetic is done the quantity) or `Fraction` in the database, and making it possible to use values in queries as they would be used by the `value` setter. The solution was to create a `quantities` table with rows for a floating point value, an integer numerator, an integer denominator, and a boolean representing whether or not the stored value should be interpreted as a decimal number (as opposed to a fraction) and create an `sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.Comparator` for the hybrid property which compares against `Quantity._float` and `Quantity.is_decimal`:

```
class Quantity(db.Model):
    # ...
    _denominator = db.Column(db.Integer)
    _float = db.Column(db.Float)
    is_decimal = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    _numerator = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # ...

    @staticmethod
    def for_cmp(val):
        """Convert val to float so it can be used to query against _float."""
        if Quantity.dec_check(val):  # True if val looks like a decimal number
            return float(val)
        elif isinstance(val, str):
            frac = Quantity.str_to_fraction(val)
        else:
            frac = Fraction(val)
        return float(frac)

    @hybrid_property
    def value(self):
        if self._float is not None:
            if self.is_decimal:
                return self._float
            elif self._denominator == 1:
                return self._numerator
            else:
                return Fraction(self._numerator, self._denominator)
        else:
            return None

    class ValueComparator(Comparator):
        def operate(self, op, other):
            return and_(op(Quantity._float, Quantity.for_cmp(other)),
                        Quantity.is_decimal == Quantity.dec_check(other))

    @value.comparator
    def value(cls):
        return Quantity.ValueComparator(cls)

    @value.setter
    def value(self, val):
        if val is not None:
            if Quantity.dec_check(val):
                self.is_decimal = True
                self._float = float(val)
                self._numerator = None
                self._denominator = None
            else:
                self.is_decimal = False
                if isinstance(val, str):
                    frac = Quantity.str_to_fraction(val)
                else:
                    frac = Fraction(val)
                self._numerator = frac.numerator
                self._denominator = frac.denominator
                self._float = float(frac)
        else:
            self.is_decimal = None
            self._numerator = None
            self._denominator = None
            self._float = None
```

Since I don't have the original model I asked this question for any longer, I can't readily go back and answer this question properly, but I'd imagine it could be done using `join` or `select`.